# After table list display who is the first rank holder

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON data table. But after that, I want to show it who is the first rank holder. I tried so many times but I didn't get it.
PFB..

```
var studentsList = [
    { "id": "1", "firstName": "rajesh", "lastName": "kumar", "sub1": "35", "sub2": "55", "sub3": "45" },
    { "id": "2", "firstName": "ranjith", "lastName": "rajesh", "sub1": "56", "sub2": "65", "sub3": "44" },
    { "id": "3", "firstName": "arun", "lastName": "LK", "sub1": "48", "sub2": "89", "sub3": "88" },
    { "id": "4", "firstName": "abinaya", "lastName": "Vishwa", "sub1": "65", "sub2": "67", "sub3": "65" },
    { "id": "5", "firstName": "ashok", "lastName": "kumar", "sub1": "33", "sub2": "44", "sub3": "100" },
    { "id": "6", "firstName": "ashwini", "lastName": "kumar", "sub1": "89", "sub2": "35", "sub3": "100" },
    { "id": "7", "firstName": "karthick", "lastName": "kanagaraj", "sub1": "90", "sub2": "89", "sub3": "63" },
    { "id": "8", "firstName": "saravanan", "lastName": "fransis", "sub1": "84", "sub2": "81", "sub3": "83" },
    { "id": "9", "firstName": "Antoty", "lastName": "john", "sub1": "55", "sub2": "100", "sub3": "65" },
    { "id": "10", "firstName": "santhosh", "lastName": "Arun", "sub1": "33", "sub2": "100", "sub3": "83" }
];
```

Comment: This is the code of total..
//Total
function getTotal(sub1, sub2, sub3) {
    var total = parseInt(sub1) + parseInt(sub2) + parseInt(sub3);
    return total;
}

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate over the array and keep a track of the current maximum.

```js
const studentsList = [
 { "id": "1", "firstName": "rajesh", "lastName": "kumar", "sub1": "35", "sub2": "55", "sub3": "45" },
 { "id": "2", "firstName": "ranjith", "lastName": "rajesh", "sub1": "56", "sub2": "65", "sub3": "44" },
 { "id": "3", "firstName": "arun", "lastName": "LK", "sub1": "48", "sub2": "89", "sub3": "88" },
 { "id": "4", "firstName": "abinaya", "lastName": "Vishwa", "sub1": "65", "sub2": "67", "sub3": "65" },
 { "id": "5", "firstName": "ashok", "lastName": "kumar", "sub1": "33", "sub2": "44", "sub3": "100" },
 { "id": "6", "firstName": "ashwini", "lastName": "kumar", "sub1": "89", "sub2": "35", "sub3": "100" },
 { "id": "7", "firstName": "karthick", "lastName": "kanagaraj", "sub1": "90", "sub2": "89", "sub3": "63" },
 { "id": "8", "firstName": "saravanan", "lastName": "fransis", "sub1": "84", "sub2": "81", "sub3": "83" },
 { "id": "9", "firstName": "Antoty", "lastName": "john", "sub1": "55", "sub2": "100", "sub3": "65" },
 { "id": "10", "firstName": "santhosh", "lastName": "Arun", "sub1": "33", "sub2": "100", "sub3": "83" }
];

let highestMarks = 0, 
      highestMarksIndex = 0;
      
studentsList.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
 const totalMarks = curr.sub1 + curr.sub2 + curr.sub3;
 
 if (totalMarks > highestMarks) {
  highestMarks = totalMarks;
  highestMarksIndex = index;
 }
 return acc;
}, {});

console.log('Highest marks student', studentsList[highestMarksIndex]);
```

Comment: Thanks.
 But the highest mark is 248 and the name is Saravanan Francis. But it's showing the first name of karthick kanagaraj.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array reducer to get the item that sums best rank:

```js
var studentsList = [
    { "id": "1", "firstName": "rajesh", "lastName": "kumar", "sub1": "35", "sub2": "55", "sub3": "45" },
    { "id": "2", "firstName": "ranjith", "lastName": "rajesh", "sub1": "56", "sub2": "65", "sub3": "44" },
    { "id": "3", "firstName": "arun", "lastName": "LK", "sub1": "48", "sub2": "89", "sub3": "88" },
    { "id": "4", "firstName": "abinaya", "lastName": "Vishwa", "sub1": "65", "sub2": "67", "sub3": "65" },
    { "id": "5", "firstName": "ashok", "lastName": "kumar", "sub1": "33", "sub2": "44", "sub3": "100" },
    { "id": "6", "firstName": "ashwini", "lastName": "kumar", "sub1": "89", "sub2": "35", "sub3": "100" },
    { "id": "7", "firstName": "karthick", "lastName": "kanagaraj", "sub1": "90", "sub2": "89", "sub3": "63" },
    { "id": "8", "firstName": "saravanan", "lastName": "fransis", "sub1": "84", "sub2": "81", "sub3": "83" },
    { "id": "9", "firstName": "Antoty", "lastName": "john", "sub1": "55", "sub2": "100", "sub3": "65" },
    { "id": "10", "firstName": "santhosh", "lastName": "Arun", "sub1": "33", "sub2": "100", "sub3": "83" }
];

bestStudent = studentsList.reduce((acc, curr) => {
 if (curr.sub1 + curr.sub2 + curr.sub3 > acc.sub1 + acc.sub2 + acc.sub3){
  acc = curr
 }
 return acc
});
console.log(bestStudent)
```

Answer (score 0):

So from the question,

**Things to be done**

1. Need to sum up the three properties sub1, sub2, sub3.
2. Sort the array based on the total value of the three properties.

**Solution Explained**

1. Instead of mutating the same array, create a new array ([array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))
2. On the new array, create a property called total, which will sum up the three property values and change the format to number by changing the type on the fly.
3. Use the inbuilt function of sort which will perform the sorting on the copy of the array ([array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort))

```js
let studentsList = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "firstName": "rajesh",
    "lastName": "kumar",
    "sub1": "35",
    "sub2": "55",
    "sub3": "45"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "firstName": "ranjith",
    "lastName": "rajesh",
    "sub1": "56",
    "sub2": "65",
    "sub3": "44"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "firstName": "arun",
    "lastName": "LK",
    "sub1": "48",
    "sub2": "89",
    "sub3": "88"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "firstName": "abinaya",
    "lastName": "Vishwa",
    "sub1": "65",
    "sub2": "67",
    "sub3": "65"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "firstName": "ashok",
    "lastName": "kumar",
    "sub1": "33",
    "sub2": "44",
    "sub3": "100"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "firstName": "ashwini",
    "lastName": "kumar",
    "sub1": "89",
    "sub2": "35",
    "sub3": "100"
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "firstName": "karthick",
    "lastName": "kanagaraj",
    "sub1": "90",
    "sub2": "89",
    "sub3": "63"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "firstName": "saravanan",
    "lastName": "fransis",
    "sub1": "84",
    "sub2": "81",
    "sub3": "83"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "firstName": "Antoty",
    "lastName": "john",
    "sub1": "55",
    "sub2": "100",
    "sub3": "65"
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "firstName": "santhosh",
    "lastName": "Arun",
    "sub1": "33",
    "sub2": "100",
    "sub3": "83"
  }
]


let sortedArrayBasedOnTotal = studentsList.map(o => ({...o, total: Number(o.sub1) + Number(o.sub2) + Number(o.sub3)})).sort((a,b) => b.total - a.total)

console.log(sortedArrayBasedOnTotal)
```

This array which is sorted you can parse into a table and show on the UI

You can access the first rank holder using accessing

`console.log(sortedArrayBasedOnTotal[0])`

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Calculate total of all subjects' marks for all students
- Step 2: Sort the students on basis of total marks
- Step 3: Get the ranks as required

```js
const studentsList = [
     { "id": "1", "firstName": "rajesh", "lastName": "kumar", "sub1": "35", "sub2": "55", "sub3": "45" },
     { "id": "2", "firstName": "ranjith", "lastName": "rajesh", "sub1": "56", "sub2": "65", "sub3": "44" },
     { "id": "3", "firstName": "arun", "lastName": "LK", "sub1": "48", "sub2": "89", "sub3": "88" },
     { "id": "4", "firstName": "abinaya", "lastName": "Vishwa", "sub1": "65", "sub2": "67", "sub3": "65" },
     { "id": "5", "firstName": "ashok", "lastName": "kumar", "sub1": "33", "sub2": "44", "sub3": "100" },
     { "id": "6", "firstName": "ashwini", "lastName": "kumar", "sub1": "89", "sub2": "35", "sub3": "100" },
     { "id": "7", "firstName": "karthick", "lastName": "kanagaraj", "sub1": "90", "sub2": "89", "sub3": "63" },
     { "id": "8", "firstName": "saravanan", "lastName": "fransis", "sub1": "84", "sub2": "81", "sub3": "83" },
     { "id": "9", "firstName": "Antoty", "lastName": "john", "sub1": "55", "sub2": "100", "sub3": "65" },
     { "id": "10", "firstName": "santhosh", "lastName": "Arun", "sub1": "33", "sub2": "100", "sub3": "83" }
    ];

// Added a new key 'total' for each student
// total = marks of subj1 + subj2 + subj3
// parseInt(string) -> For converting string to integer for mathematical operation
    studentsList.forEach(function(part, index, studentsList) {
  studentsList[index]['total'] = parseInt(studentsList[index]['sub1']) + parseInt(studentsList[index]['sub2']) + parseInt(studentsList[index]['sub3']);
});

// Here is the sorting of students on basis of 'total'
studentsList.sort((a,b) => (a.total > b.total) ? 1 : ((b.total > a.total) ? -1 : 0));
    
// Last student will have the first rank
// studentsList.length - 1 = last student in the sorted list

console.log('First rank student detail')
console.log(studentsList[studentsList.length - 1])

// All students
console.log('All students details')
console.log(studentsList)
```